# Updating parent scope on UI router state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

When changing state with UI router query params are being added. In this case 'size'

Within the parent controller 'indexAppCtrl' the scope property attached to  $stateParams.size doesn't update on state change, however the $stateParams object does.

As a fix I've added a listener on $stateChangeSuccess but it feels hacky. Is there a better way of ensuring the scope is updates with stateParams changes?

app.js

```
var indexApp = angular.module('indexApp', ['ui.router']);

indexApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
    .state('wizard', {
        url: '/wizard?size',
        templateUrl: 'wizard/wizard.html',
        params: {
            size: 'large'
        }
    })

 });
```

indexAppCtrl.js

```
    var indexApp = angular.module('indexApp');

    indexApp.controller('indexAppCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.welcome = "welcome to....";

        $scope.stateParams = $stateParams;
        //updates

        $scope.size = $stateParams.size;
        // doesn't update

        $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
            $scope.size = $stateParams.size;
            //updates
        });

    }]);
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="indexApp" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main ng-controller="indexAppCtrl">

        <button ui-sref="wizard">Start the wizard</button>

        <ui-view>

        </ui-view>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is not hacky. The `$scope.size` property is not updated because the controller is not re-created when the state changes.

The [$stateChangeSuccess](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) is the defined way to update a component once the state transition has been completed so your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that, just attach the refernce of `$state.params`(global storage of state parameter) to scope variable, which will be getting updated on & when any changes occur in `$state` parameters.

```
$scope.params = $state.params;
```